# Is Qatar accepting unvaccinated U.S. citizens for traveling?

Tags: usa, covid-19, qatar

I’m a U.S. citizen and want to go to Qatar for traveling and visiting some distant relatives. Previously I could just go there without any visa, only my passport and easily travel for 30 days. Now I read these requirements https://qa.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-11/  and I’m not sure. It says the U.S. citizens can enter with a a vaccine. However, I’m not vaccinated. I have a doctor’s note saying I should be exempt from vaccination. So can or cannot I enter Qatar with a negative PRC test?

Answer (score 17):

Qatar's entry and quarantine policy can found [here](https://covid19.moph.gov.qa/EN/travel-and-return-policy/Pages/default.aspx).

Currently, entry from a Green list country is possible for travellers  who are not vaccinated or who have not completed the necessary vaccination doses, but there is a mandatory hotel quarantine at a designated hotel for 7 days along with mandatory PCR tests before and after arrival. If you have a pre-issued family visa as a first-degree relative, you may be allowed to quarantine at home if certain conditions are met.